# Having problem with installing Craft

Tags: installation

I am trying to install Craft on my server and I've hit a snug which I can't overcome, because I am just not that technically proficient.

I think I've followed all of the instructions on the Craft website to a t, however when I tried to get to the admin panel, I get the following error:

Could not find your `craft/` folder. Please ensure that `$craftPath` is set correctly in `/home/toaeroplano/public_html/index.php`

I did some Googling on that and I found out that this might be an issue with `open_basedir` permissions.

So I went to my php.ini file and I saw that this was edited out. Like this:

```
; open_basedir, if set, limits all file operations to the defined directory
; and below.  This directive makes most sense if used in a per-directory
; or per-virtualhost web server configuration file. This directive is
; *NOT* affected by whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off.
;open_basedir =
```

So I changed it to:

```
open_basedir = ON (and took the ; off)
```

So now I get a "No input file specified." message.

What can I do? Like I said, this is far from being my area of expertise.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's likely your `/craft` directory couldn't be found. Out of the box, Craft expects it's `/craft` directory to be located just outside the root directory of the website. So by the looks of it from your path, your `index.php` file is located here:

```
/home/toaeroplano/public_html/
```

So that would mean you `/craft` directory should be located here:

```
/home/toaeroplano/
```

If I were you I'd put the php.ini settings back to what they were so you get the original error, then make sure you've copied the `/craft` directory from the installation into the directory above. If you want your `/craft` directory somewhere else you need to edit the `index.php` and specify where the directory lives. So edit this line in `index.php`:

```
$craftPath = '../craft';
```

The `..` in the path just means the directory above, so if you wanted it to live in the `/home` directory, you change it to this:

```
$craftPath = '../../craft';
```

EDIT: Also make sure the permissions on the `/craft/app/`, `craft/config/` and `craft/storage/` are set as per the [install docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/installing#step-2-set-the-permissions).

Answer (score 0):

`open_basedir` is actually expecting a path (like `/home/toaeroplano`) and   some hosts use it as a form of "jailing" their users to help make sure PHP can't access anything from *outside* whatever value is set there.

As Steve mentioned in his answer, don't set it unless you know what you're doing. I don't know how you're hosting Craft, but some hosts will lock down the server in other ways—for example, `mod_security` might be preventing you from hitting anything outside the web root as well—in your case `/public_html/`—so you may have to set `$craftPath` to `./craft` so it's looking in the same "folder" and move your `craft` folder to `public_html`.